# Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \int_{0}^{1}e^{-nx}f(x)dx=f(0)$ when $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \int_{0}^{1}e^{-nx}f(x)dx=f(0)$

I am making a claim, 
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \int_{0}^{1}e^{-nx}f(0) dx=f(0).$ Is it really true?

Comment: Evaluate the integral. $f(0)$ is constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without using LDCT**

We have

$$I_n = \int_0^1 ne^{-nx}f(x)\, dx= \int_0^1 ne^{-nx}[f(x) - f(0)] \, dx + f(0)\int_0^1 ne^{-nx} \, dx \\ = \int_0^c ne^{-nx}[f(x) - f(0)] \, dx +  \int_c^1 ne^{-nx}[f(x) - f(0)] \, dx + f(0)(1- e^{-n}),$$

and

$$\left| I_n - f(0)\right| \leqslant \int_0^c ne^{-nx}|f(x) - f(0)| \, dx +  \int_c^1 ne^{-nx}|f(x) - f(0)| \, dx + |f(0)|e^{-n}$$

For any $\epsilon > 0,$ choose $c$ sufficiently small such that $|f(x) - f(0)| < \epsilon$ for $ 0 < x < c$.

Then

$$|I_n - f(0)| \leqslant \epsilon(1 - e^{-nc}) + (2\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)|)(e^{-nc}- e^{-n}) + |f(0)|e^{-n} .$$

Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}|I_n - f(0)| \leqslant \epsilon.$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small, it follows that $\lim I_n = f(0).$

**Using LDCT**

Alternatively, changing variables with $u = nx,$ we have

$$n \int_{0}^{1}e^{-nx}f(x)dx=\int_0^ne^{-u}f(u/n) \, du = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}f(u/n)1\{u \leqslant n\} \, du $$

Since $f$ is continuous, $f(u/n) \to f(0)$ as $n \to \infty$, and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{-u}f(u/n)1\{u \leqslant n\} = f(0)e^{-u}$$

By the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}f(u/n)1\{u \leqslant n\} \, du = \int_0^{\infty}f(0)e^{-u}\, du = f(0)$$

Comment: actually I am in precollege , so I don't know LDCT. can you pose a simpler proof?

Comment: LDCT allows you to switch the limit and the integral

Comment: I was actually thinking of breaking the interval into parts say $(0, \delta)$ and $(\delta,1)$ and I think it is enough to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \int_{0}^{1}e^{-nx}(f(x)-f(0))=0$

Comment: can you tell me what this $1$ in your integral suggests here:$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}f(u/n)1\{u \leqslant n\} \, du $$??

Comment: the indicator function $= 1 \,\,\text{if} \,\,u \leqslant n $ and $= 0 \,\,\text{if} \,\,u > n.$ It lets us put the upper limit to $\infty$ but it has no effect on the limit of the integrand

Comment: I can show you a simpler way.

Comment: Please see modified answer which finds limit with calculus and not Lebesgue.

Comment: perfect solution!! very nice..

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad you asked for an alternative to the LDCT.

Comment: It took me a few moments to realize LDCT stands for Lebesgue dominated convergence :-P.

Comment: Just can you clarify once more why $|f(x)-f(0)|<2 \sup|f(x)|$?

Comment: @AyanBiswas: Because $f$ is bounded and by the triangle inequality $|f(x) - f(0)| \leqslant |f(x)| + |f(0)| \leqslant 2M$ where $M$ is an upper bound for $f$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Fine..I get it now..thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Use integration by parts:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} n\left[\left.{\frac{f(x)e^{-nx}}{n}}\right|^0_1-\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)e^{-nx}\text{d}x\right] $$

$$ = f(0) - \lim_{n\to\infty}f(1)e^{-n} - \int_{0}^{1}\lim_{n\to\infty}f'(x)e^{-nx}\text{d}x $$

$$ = f(0) $$

Comment: It is not told that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: You're right, my bad.